# My android xamarin form app is restarted by itself

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I Just developed my first app with xamarin forms.
Its an app to collect photos and gps and send it to the server.
Every thing is working except User open the app the main page is loaded. Then he navigates to another page and minimize de app when he opens the app again it is not on the page the user navegated to its on the main page.

I don't know where to start . What could I do?

Comment: What does "main page is pushed automatically" mean?  Is there a different page you expect to load?  Typically the main page of an app is intended to load as soon as the app finishes launching.

Comment: User open the app the main page is loaded. Then he navigates to another page and minimize de app when he opens the app again it is noto on the page the user navegated to its on the main page.

Comment: See, if you had included that relevant information in your original post it would have been much easier to help you.  It sounds like Android is killing the app because of a resource issue (or he is manually killing the app) forcing it to restart.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the guidence I'm real beginner in a previous version of the app the app ended and disappear from the app list i set the linker  configuration for no linkage at all and started to restart the app but I didn't notice it was a restart sorry I'm going to change my original post. Do you know what I can do to debug this ?

Comment: What seems to be happening is the app is being restarted because of low resources. The question is how can I avoid that? Is there a way to set priority of the app as high so Android won't close it?

Comment: is your app the culprit?  Then fix that!  Otherwise you can attempt to maintain the state yourself and reload the appropriate page when the app is restarted

Comment: What is culprit? Is it the name of an app? if it is then the answer is no my app is TrackLaser. I don't need only to keep on the right page I need to avoid the restart because the gps and photo capture are in a background process using TPL and they cannot be stoped.

Comment: "culprit" means "person responsible" - I was asking if your app was the one causing the resource drain

Comment: I don't know if the app is the culprit the only thing I know is had consumed 7.1 Mb in the last 3 hours.

Comment: That's not much.  It sounds like this is a design issue - your app needs to be able to do background transfers and have the ability to resume them in they are interrupted.  You can't control what Android does, or how other apps on the device behave, you can only ensure that your app is able to detect interrupted transfers and resume them.

Comment: Thanks for your point of view. I don't know how to resume them can you give a direction?